# how to call grails resources plugin's "use" tag as a method

Tags: grails, groovy, taglib

I'm trying to invoke a tag defined by the [resources plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/resources). The local name of this tag is "use" which is a Groovy keyword. I have tried calling it with :

```
r.use( module:"jquery" )
ResourceTagLib.metaClass.invokeMethod( "use", [name:"jquery"])
r."use"( module:"jquery" )
```

but I get the error:

> ```
> Expecting at least 2 arguments, a category class and a Closure
> ```

is there any way around it?

Comment: Maybe `grailsApplication.getArtefact(TagLibArtefactHandler.TYPE, 'ResourceTagLib')` will return a necessary instance?

Answer (score 2):

The plugin is very new and not even officially released - it's still in release-candidate stage. So stackoverflow is probably a bad place to ask this question since so few here would have used it.

There's a new Grails plugin forum that the plugin author (Marc Palmer) watches, so your best bet is to ask there: http://grails-plugins.847840.n3.nabble.com/

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I've posted it here http://grails-plugins.847840.n3.nabble.com/how-to-call-resources-plugin-s-use-tag-as-a-method-td2499907.html